# How the tube of a tire get puncture?

Tags: pressure

How the tube of a tire(cycle) get puncture? I mean, the inner tube is protected by an outer tube, so how is it possible to make a hole in the inner tube? And in general the puncture hole is very small. Why?

Comment: Because of nails and glass.

Answer (score 1):

When a nail is driven into a tire, it is safe to assume that it happens 
in the first contact. The reason for this assumption is that the surface 
of the tire is compliant (bouncy like a spring) so as soon as contact has 
been made and the nail is lodged in the thread, if no puncture exists, 
repeatedly pushing on the nail will not make any progress, rather it will 
push against the compliant surface of the tire (which makes a "tent" 
around the nail") with no energy being transfered to the tire (no 
puncture). The part of the nail that sticks out will simply be polished 
flush over time against the surface of the thread. Remember that pushing 
on an elastic object (like a spring) causes energy to be absorbed by the 
spring, only to be released once the force is relieved. And energy would 
have be spent in the puncture. Also, the hardness of the tire is unlikely 
to suddenly be reduced to allow the nail to penetrate in a subsequent 
rotation. Finally, the force driving the nail can be assumed to be about 
the same on each rotation (a fraction of the car's weight, as distributed 
according to its dimensions, acceleration rate and grade of pavement, all 
of these are parameters that change slowly from one tire rotation to 
another during normal driving, and can be assumed to be about the same)